# How to install Fedora server 31 or ubuntu server 19.10 on orange pi 3?

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, system-installation, arm, arm64

I have a [Orange pi 3](http://www.orangepi.org/Orange%20Pi%203/), I have tried many ways to install [Fedora server 31 (aarch64 version )](https://getfedora.org/en/server/download/) on my board but all of them were unsuccessful:

1. I wrote Fedora-Server-dvd-aarch64-31-1.9_2.iso on a TF card via balena Etcher. Then I put the card in its slot and powered on the board, but Das u-boot just booted default android tv (installed from factory on board) and didn't boot the fedora image. I deleted Das u-boot and android tv partition using fdisk on [orange pi modified version of ubuntu 16.04 Xenial](https://www.orangepi.org/downloadresources/OrangePi3/2019-01-23/orangepi3_b0c3dac8d3483dab6eb392b0a9.html). I retried booting fedora server 31 from card but the board just showed processor (Allwinner H6) logo and froze in this level.
2. I tested the raw image of fedora server 31 aarch64 version but I got same result.
3. I tried installing [Ubuntu server 19.10 arm](https://ubuntu.com/download/server/arm) too but I just faced with that processor logo.

**update**:I took the TF card out an when I restart the borad saw the allwinner logo again that means the borad didn't recognized those medias as bootable media !

I really need help installing fedora 31 server or Ubuntu 19.10 server on my board.

Comment: First verify that this image is an image that should work with your device, and TF card is a boot device. Then show us how you write it to the TF card.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor all images hashes was checked

Comment: Then show us how you write it to the TF card.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor  As I said in question text  I used balena Etcher . the etcher flashes images to USB drive and then checks health of written data therefore there is not any problem with boot media

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor The card model is SanDisk Ultra (SDHC 1 technology) 16 Gb